# Quotient ring of a maximal ideal and a subideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, quotient-spaces

If $R$ is a ring, let $I\subseteq R$ be a maximal ideal. Suppose $J\subseteq I\subseteq R$ is also an ideal. What is the relation between $R/I$ and $R/J$? Like, is $R/I\subseteq R/J$ or vice versa?

Comment: By the 3rd isomorphism theorem, $R/I$ is a quotient of $R/J$: $$(R/J)\big/(I/J)\simeq R/I.$$

Comment: Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and let $p$ be a prime number. Consider $I  = (p)$ and $J = (p^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$R/I$ is the set of cosets for $I$, and $R/J$ is the set of cosets for $J$. Neither one is a subset of the other.

If you're having trouble visualizing this, try with $R=\mathbb Z$ and $I=(2)$ and $J=(6)$.

The only easy relationship you have is that $(R/J)/(I/J)\cong R/I$.

Perhaps a more interesting observation is that $I/J$ is a maximal ideal of $R/J$, and this is just a reflection of the fact that maximal ideals of $R/J$ correspond to maximal ideals of $R$ containing $J$.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that $I/J$ is a maximal ideal of $R/J$. and that there is a surjective ring homomorphism $R/J\to R/I$ (with kernel $I/J$).

In general you can neither embed $R/I$ into $R/J$ nor $R/J$ into $R/I$. For instance, if $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $J=\{0\}$.